# Initialise a vector with 1's at indexes set in another vector

Tags: matlab, octave

Given a vector:

```
v1 = [1 ; 3; 5]
```

and **without using a for loop** how could you create a new vector `v2 of length n`  with:

**each element of v2 set to 1 if it's index is in v1, 0 otherwise**.

So for example, given the above v1 and `n = 8` I would expect v2 to have values:

```
v2 = [1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>> v2 = zeros(n,1);
>> v2(v1) = 1;
```